# Terminal commands are truncated when scrolling through history

Tags: terminal

Pretty simple question, when I press the up arrow to scroll through previous commands, they show up as truncated, even though the terminal is wide enough (and displays output beyond the truncation point):

```
[2017-10-02 17:38:34,046] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
<er my.zook.com:2181 --list
```

The last line in that shows the truncated command, which should have been along the lines of `./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper my.zook.com:2181 --list`. Any help getting it to stop truncating would be great. Thanks!

Comment: what was the command supposed to be?

Comment: Updated to show the command

Comment: What shell are you using? And do you have any shell rc files in your home folder?

Comment: I just open terminal, source a `.bashrc`, which sets some login info for something and sets color options.

Comment: What terminal type is Terminal set to in Preferences -> Advanced  Terminfo?  Is this changed in  your .bashrc?

Comment: `xterm-256color` - no